# Ruby: How to pass parameters to oj_serializers

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I'm using Oj Serializer: https://github.com/ElMassimo/oj_serializers.

I want to know how can I pass some variable(eg. CurrentCurrent) from controller to Serializer?

This for example controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
def index
    render json: { albums: AlbumSerializer.many(albums) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/ElMassimo/oj_serializers/blob/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#controller--params-):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action { Thread.current[:current_controller] = self }
end

class BaseJsonSerializer < Oj::Serializer
  def scope
    @scope ||= Thread.current[:current_controller]
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= scope&.current_user
  end
end
```

Note: it is a bad practice.